# Django package multiple files in a single download

Tags: django, file, packaging

In Django I'm looking for a way to serve several different files at once. I can't use static archives (.zip, .tar, etc.) because I don't have enough storage to cache these files and it will take far too long to generate them on the fly (each could be in the 100s of megabytes).

Is there a way I can indicate to the browser that several files are coming its way? Perhaps there is a container format that I can indicate before streaming files to the user?

Edit: There could be hundreds of files in each package so asking the user to download each one is very time consuming.

Comment: Any reason you can't just give the user links to the multiple files and have them download each individually?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It seems like generating them on the fly is really your only option, and I think that's not as bad a situation to be in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the .tar file format can be streamed. I'll experiment with this for now.

http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html